# What is the java 8 equivalent to History in GWT?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a GWT program to java 8. In GWT I have:

```
History.newItem("joeyAwardOverview", true);
```

I have tried to replace it with:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, JoeyAwardOverviewView.class));
```

However, "Intent" is not recognised. What is the correct code please?

I have spent hours on this and found:

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();  

    response.sendRedirect("SelectPerson.html");

    pw.close();
```

However, this displays the html code in the target html file at the end of the current page instead of displaying the target page[image]

Then I found this way:

```
submitHandler : function(contactForm) {
        //do something here
        var frm = $('#contactForm');
        //alert($("#accountName").val());

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "LoginView",
            cache: false,
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "1"){
                    window.location.assign("SelectPerson.html");
                }else{
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
                    $("#accountName").focus();
                }
                //console.log('Submission was successful.');
                //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

In the java simply:

```
response.getWriter().write("1");
```

Comment: Aside from the term "joeyAwardOverview", these code snippets have nothing to do with each other. Why would you expect that to work? What is ``History.newItem``?

Comment: Intents are Android, not Java 8.

Comment: And GWT is referring to browser history.  Java 8 cannot access the browser history of the user's web browser.

Comment: In GWT "History.newItem("joeyAwardOverview", true);" displays the next view. OK, I have been searching for the java equivalent and "startActivity(new Intent(this, JoeyAwardOverviewView.class));" was all I found. So my question still stands - how do I display the next view in java please?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do ? Upgrading a GWT program to Java 8 ? Modifying a GWT program to a desktop Java program with swing or javafx ? Modifying a GWT program to an Android app ?

Comment: I am having to many issues with GWT so I am creating a new project using Java 8 EE, jquery, bootstrap and Tomcat 8. I have not used JEE before so I having a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
submitHandler : function(contactForm) {
        //do something here
        var frm = $('#contactForm');
        //alert($("#accountName").val());

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "LoginView",
            cache: false,
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "1"){
                    window.location.assign("SelectPerson.html");
                }else{
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
                    $("#accountName").focus();
                }
                //console.log('Submission was successful.');
                //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

In the java simply:

```
response.getWriter().write("1");
```

By returning different numbers and testing for them you can divert to different pages. For instance if you login as an Administrator show the administration page, if a Leader show a list of Scouts, etc.